# Sqlalchemy reuse sub query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to reuse my subquery for multi times.

First count

```
 devices = db.session.query(subquery).count()
```

sub query like

```
 (Device, User).\
                    filter(Device.e=='E').\
                 filter(Device.id==User.id
```

then paginate the result with limit. I want to reuse my filters

```
(subquery).paginate(page=offset, per_page=limit)
```

and not to duplicate because I use so many filters and filter may change

Answer (score 1):

The answer is actually very simple.

```
def getquery(self):
  return db.session.query(subquery)
```

for count

```
count = self.getquery().count()
```

for limit

```
devices = self.getquery().limit(xxxx)
```